# How to use strip function in conjunction with the split function for elements in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, strip

I am making a program that creates a dictionary of a list of colleges, and their rank in terms of applicant preferences.

Here is what I've created:

```
list1=input("Please write some universities you want to attend, separated by commas, with your first choice first.\n")

list1=list1.strip()
list1=list1.split(",")

ranking=range(1,len(list1)+1)
dictionary_of_colleges={rank:school for rank,school in zip(ranking,list1)}
print(dictionary_of_colleges)
```

It mostly does what I intend for it to do. The only thing is, when I input a list of colleges, there's a white space in front of the college name and I can't seem to figure out how to strip that white space away.

For example, this input for list1:

```
UPenn, Georgia Tech, Texas, Eastern, NW Missouri State
```

Gets this output:

```
{1: 'UPenn', 2: ' Georgia Tech', 3: ' Texas', 4: ' Eastern', 5: ' NW Missouri State'}
```

While I could just ask the user to input the names of the colleges *without* a space after the comma, I'd rather the program itself be able to strip the white space away.

As you can see, I've tried using the strip function, but it doesn't seem to work.
Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
dictionary_of_colleges={rank:school for rank,school in zip(ranking,list1)}
```

to

```
dictionary_of_colleges={rank:school.strip() for rank,school in zip(ranking,list1)}
```

The strip function removes white spaces from the beginning and end of a string. In your usage, it is removing the spaces from the beginning and end of the whole list of schools, but not from each individual school.

Also note that you can omit the creation of `ranking` and just use `enumerate(list1, 1)` as in

```
dictionary_of_colleges={rank:school.strip() for rank,school in enumerate(list1,1)}
```

Where the 1 in enumerate tells it to start at index 1.